# Forcing Yakuake run on certain screen at KDE startup

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, yakuake

I've got an external monitor that I'm sometimes plug into my notebook running Kubuntu 22.04.
KDE is configured to set external monitor as primary one.

My favorite terminal application is Yakuake, that I run in the KDE autostart.

My issue is the following.
Sometimes I launch the system and/or shut it down without the external monitor plugged in.
At the moment of the system shutting down without the external monitor, Yakuake is running on the laptop embedded screen.

Next time, when I launch the system with the external monitor already plugged in, Yakuake still stays on the embedded laptop's screen, and I have to manually click on its Option menu -> Screen -> Screen 1.

I've tried to run KDE pre-startup script that fixes Yakuake config. The script is below, however, it does not help.

```
❯ cat ~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/force_yakuake_screen.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh

sed -i -e 's/Screen=.+/Screen=1/' ~/.config/yakuakerc
```

When I fire up the system and check contents of `~/.config/yakuakerc`, it contains "Screen=1", but the application already runs on the Screen 2 (laptop's embedded) at that moment.

I've tried to move Yakuake to different screens manually through the option menu, and these motions have been immediately reflected in `~/.config/yakuakerc`.

This suggests that Yakuake somehow ignores this setting on first launch though the autostart.

I don't think that this pre-startup script runs after Yakuake, because my directory `~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/` contains a couple of other scripts that set environment variables. And these variables are set in the shell running inside Yakuake.

Remaining method to resolve my issue is to command Yakuake to change its screen through DBus.

I've inspected Yakuake DBus interface but haven't found any methods that could help me:

```
❯ for pth in $(qdbus org.kde.yakuake) ; do
    echo $pth
    qdbus org.kde.yakuake $pth | grep -i screen
done
```

Output

```
/
/MainApplication
/Sessions
/Sessions/1
/Windows
/Windows/1
/org
/org/kde
/org/kde/yakuake
/yakuake
/yakuake/MainWindow_1
property read bool org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.fullScreen
method void org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.showFullScreen()
/yakuake/sessions
/yakuake/tabs
/yakuake/window
```

The output shows the boolean property `org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.fullScreen` and the method `org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.showFullScreen()` in the path `/yakuake/MainWindow_1` however, they are not about moving the application on certain screens.

Searching [through sources](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AKDE%2Fyakuake%20setScreen&type=code) suggests that function `MainWindow::setScreen`, responsible for this, is not exposed to the DBus interface.

Could anyone confirm or disprove my latest guess?

Could anyone suggest a way to achieve my goal (force yakuake to always run on Screen 1)?